# Python Tornado: Is this secure?

Tags: python-2.7, security, tornado, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm a bit of a noob here, so I'm trying to figure out some basics about web security. I have a very basic Tornado server running, and while it's only for use by me, I want to make sure I'm not making any obvious security mistakes.

1) Every handler except the login handler is decorated by `@tornado.web.authenticated`. Could non-authenticated users submit to, e.g., my AJAX handler, etc? (i.e. how much do I have to worry about them?)

2) Here's my login and authentication deal:

```
def do_auth(name, password):
  with open(auth_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
  for l in lines:
    u,s,h = l.strip().split(':')
    if name == u:
      s5 = hashlib.sha512()
      s5.update(s.decode('hex'))
      s5.update(password)
      if h == s5.hexdigest():
        return True
  return False

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write('<html><body><form action="/login" method="post">'
               'Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />'
               'Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />'
               '<input type="submit" value="Sign in">'
               '</form></body></html>')

  def post(self):
    if do_auth(self.get_argument("name"), self.get_argument("password")):
      self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("name"))
      self.redirect("/")
    else:
      self.redirect("/login")
```

The point is that untrusted input is being used only in python's urllib.sha512.update() function and for a string comparison. Is this "secure"? [Note: the auth file was made by hand, no functionality in the code to change it.]

3) Generally speaking, what other things should I be worried about?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and answer some of this:

(1)

> > Every handler except the login handler is decorated by @tornado.web.authenticated. Could non-authenticated users submit to, e.g.my AJAX handler

If your AJAX handler is decorated with @tornado.web.authenticated then the user will have to be logged in to call it.

If it is not decorated it is accessible by anyone and you make the data publicly viewable and or writeable. Publicly viewable may be ok but publicly writable is probably bad. It depends what your data is.

(2) You dont need to write your own do_auth() function just a

```
def get_login_url(self):
        return u"/login"
```

function to point to your login page

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't include the settings section. I have a `login_url="/login"` in the settings dict (that gets passed to the `tornado.web.Application` constructor). My understanding is that Tornado doesn't have any authentication mechanism built in, so you have to do your own. My question boils down to: "Is it safe to put un-scrubbed input into the `update()` function?"